# Why does this function only run once?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I really think this should run every 100ms, but it only beeps once.

I know about setInterval, but this confuses me.

```
var test = function () {
    console.log('beep')
    setTimeout( test, 100 );
}();
```

Anybody know why this only runs once and not forever?

Comment: Hint: `var test = function() { console.log('beep'); setTimeout( test, 100); return "I am not a function"; }(); console.log(test);`

Comment: @torazaburo perhaps you should do the same

Comment: "The same" = run it in the console.  The call to `setTimeout(undefined, 100)` unfortunately does not produce an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The anonymous function is being executed before it's assigned to `test`.

You can declare it as a named function expression:

```js
(function test() {
  console.log('beep')
  setTimeout(test, 100);
})();
```

Or postpone calling the function until after the assignment:

```js
var test = function() {
  console.log('beep')
  setTimeout(test, 100);
};
test();
```

Comment: It's not anonymous, I put a `var` in there and gave it a name and everything, what about hoisting? (head explodes) Thanks! Now if only we could figure out the Google query question for this answer...

Comment: @DigitalDesignDj Your code declares a variable called "test" and then assigns the return value of an immediately invoked function expression to it.  No brackets are required for the IIFE because the compiler already understands that it is an expression, not a declaration.  (BTW, the return value is undefined, but honey badger^Hthe compiler don't care)

Comment: @DigitalDesignDj It's anonymous in the sense that it doesn't have a name to reference it by until after the assignment operation. You may be interested in reading [`Function#name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name).

Answer (score 2):

The OP made the variable `test` the return value of the function, not the function itself.

You can do:

```
var test = function(){
    setTimeout(test,100);
};
test();
```

Or

```
(function test() {
  setTimeout(test, 100);
})();
```

Comment: It `test` is not a function (and it's not), test() will obviously fail, no?

Comment: I'm saying in OP's code, he made `test` the return value of the anonymous function.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit to show what exactly you recommend changing. I think I understand, but it's not very clear.

Comment: I think this answer is basically right. test is not being set to anything. That is why the code does not loop.

Comment: Sorry about that. Answered on the phone. Now edited it to make it more clear.

Answer (score -1):

Below link contains the answer I.e. creation phase followed by execution phase. test variable is undefined in execution phase...when function executes.
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv_5Zv5c-Ts

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Essential part is execution phase where test is set to undefined by JavaScript runtime engine in creation phase. Also I have added the reference link

Answer (score -3):

**Try Like This**

```
var test = function () {
console.log('beep');
}
setInterval(test, 300);
```

Comment: The OP knows about setInterval. This doesn't answer their question.